# How to Create Great Looking Buttons in .Net?

Tags: c#, windows, graphics

I work on C# window 05 and I want to create some great looking buttons like Vista's theme buttons, Animated buttons, or like any custom of VS05 buttons....

How can I create custom buttons like this on window platform?

Comment: Did you seriously just tag this not-programming-related on a programming question website?

Comment: @Sneakyness: That tag was added by another user. Sneakyness, imo.

Comment: @Sneakyness - its a tag to help us higher rep people find questions to close.

Comment: @^, ^^: Wasn't aware, but now I know. Thanks.

Comment: Another app using fancy glitter to disguise the fact its really only a few text boxes and a couple of buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are just Controls that respond to mouse clicks. One way would be to create your own User Control in VS05 and have your frames ready as bitmap files to load at program launch. Then subscribe to your Control's mouseOver and mouseClick events to change what image is painted on your Control at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Third party libraries like [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winextras.aspx#Overview) and [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/) have lots of cool controls and some nice themes. You just need to set some property to make a button look like a Vista button. But you will have to purchase these libraries. They also offer some trial downloads.